# How do I raise an exception when user wants to import everything using import * in Python?

Tags: python

I want to inhibit user from importing like this:

```
from module.sub import *
```

This should raise and exception and do not let anything come in the namespace unless user imports anything specific like this:

```
from module.sub import apples
```

Comment: We're all consenting adults here; if they want to do that, why stop them?

Comment: Because there are things in the `sub` which will override stuff imported from `module`.

Comment: If the objective is to avoid the user getting some internal function, checkout the `__all__` variable.

Comment: no need to raise an exception but use the `__all__` variable to define what is imported or not

Comment: That seems like something you should fix in your project structure, rather than imposing on the user.

Comment: Consider this is my only way out. :)

Comment: No. Defining `__all__` is your way out, as others have stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `module.sub`:

```
__all__ = []
```

It won't raise an exception, but when someone does `from module.sub import *`, <strike>nothing will be imported</strike> `module.sub` will still be initialized, added to `sys.modules`, and added to the local namespace, but none of the names defined in `module.sub` will be added to the namespace.

You could then refer to `module.sub.apples` but not `apples` directly.

---

If you really want an exception, at the cost of being a bit confusing, you could do:

```
__all__ = ['not_defined']
```

then:

```
>>> from module.sub import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'not_defined'
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily the nice folks made python open source so you can certainly do this

download the appropriate source here  https://www.python.org/downloads/source/

modify [import.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/import.c) , so that it raises an error if it gets the splat...

or modify the [Grammar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Grammar/Grammar) to ignore the splat (which will require also changing the [Parser](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/parsermodule.c)

once you do one of those things simply recompile python and use your new python instead of the standard one  (simply recompile may be a bit misleading on the complexity of this step)

## OR MORE SIMPLY JUST USE `__ALL__ = []` in your modules `__init__.py`

Comment: Presumably pip installing the package in question would recompile their local python with the necessary changes and reinstall it to /usr/bin for them? :)